# Downcast from 'String?!' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!!'? in swift

Tags: swift

[image]

source-code are bellow

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
                        if let blogs = json["profile_image_url"] as? String {

                            userImage = blogs//json["profile_image_url"] as! String
                            print("USER IMAGE:\(userImage)")
```

how i solve this issue

Comment: just make it like this `json["profile_image_url"] as String?`

Comment: @Pyro Avoid force-unwrapping wherever possible, it leads to bugs and runtime crashes.

Comment: @luk2302 its work perfectly . i have an other problem
 let comments = unwrapResults.items as! Array<DDBCommentRow>
Error is Ambiguous use of items

Comment: what is the error there? What does the compiler say? of what type are the involved variables?

Comment: @luk2302 That will cause an error, you should downcast with `as?` and test if the cast succeeds.

Comment: @KennethBruno correct, sry...

Comment: @luk2302 No problem, `Optional` values can be tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to test and unwrap any `Optional` before you use them. This includes casts like `as?`. If you can avoid it you should not use forced-unwrapping or explicitly-unwrapped `Optional` (marked with a `!`) because they lead to unexpected runtime crashes.

```
import Foundation

// create test data
let testJson = ["profile_image_url": "http://some.site.com/"]
var data: NSData?

// convert to NSData as JSON
do {
  data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(testJson, options: [])
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}

// decode NSData
do {
  // test and unwrap data
  if let data = data {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
    // test and unwrap cast to String
    if let userImage = json["profile_image_url"] as? String {
      print("USER IMAGE:\(userImage)")
    }
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Wait so you are also doing `if let XXX = json["profile_image_url"] as? String`, like OP. What's the difference?

Comment: The main difference is that I'm handling all the `Optional` unwrapping and errors around that statement which the OP was not. Once the code gets to that point everything should be valid and should produce no issues.